# how to solve this php mysql warning

Tags: php, mysql

My code is as following:

```
$br_code=$_SESSION["br_code"];
echo $sqlstr="select DISTINCT branch_assets.s_id,s_name
              from branch_assets,assets
              where assets.s_id=branch_assets.s_id and
              br_code='$br_code'";
echo $result=mysql_query($sqlstr);
while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
}
```

But on the line of while loop it show me warning as

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\System_management\send_in_maintanance1.php

where is my mistake please help to find this.

Comment: add mysql_error to your query and use error reporting, what does that throw you?

Comment: what is the value of `$br_code` here?

Comment: you should use `mysqli` or `PDO`

Comment: maybe `$br_code` is a string

Comment: Why `echo $result=mysql_query($sqlstr)` that is going to be a result object..

Comment: use like this `$result = mysql_query($sqlstr) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." ".$sqlstr);`

Comment: make sure you started the session also; did you? does that session array have a value to start with?

Comment: use '$br_code' insted of $br_code

Comment: Smit: you need to get in the convo here. What does `var_dump($br_code);` produce? Your question may get closed based on the possible duplicate I posted.

Comment: @PurushotamThakur still showing me same worning

Comment: I have a few thoughts why it's failing but you're not telling us the whole story here. Again; did you start the session? Does the session array have a value? are you connecting with mysql_? mysqli_? PDO? Other? the question is too unclear.

Comment: its better to run your query manuly in PHP my admin, `echo $sqlstr="select DISTINCT branch_assets.s_id,s_name
              from branch_assets,assets
              where assets.s_id=branch_assets.s_id and
              br_code=$br_code";`

Comment: @devpro in phpmyadmin when i run this query it shows me output which i wants

Comment: ok, I'm out of this one. Ask the guy with the answer below. I've done what I could here.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: u r right, and OP dont want to read your comment :p

Comment: @devpro Pffft... try and help and ask questions; I get midnight when it's really 9am here.

Comment: alright, u tried `'$br_code'` not work, u tried echo YOUR QUERY and run into php myadmin, still not work, than you must need to check your session and mysql_error()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$sqlstr="select DISTINCT branch_assets.s_id,s_name from branch_assets,assets where assets.s_id = branch_assets.s_id and br_code='".$br_code."'";
```

It's best to switch to either mysqli or PDO with a prepared statement instead of mysql_, since it is deprecated and deleted from PHP 7.0.

Reference:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Comment: did u mean this `where assets.s_id = branch_assets.s_id = '".$br_code."'`?

Comment: yes. sorry I missed the first equal

Comment: I edited it for you.

Comment: but seriously, i didn't down vote this ..

Comment: @devpro actually that didn't solve it and I have a feeling why, yet the OP isn't yet giving us the right time of day yet. OP said: *"@PurushotamThakur still showing me same worning – Smit Saraiya 28 secs ago"*

Comment: @Fred-ii-: true